PowerShell ForEach Loop - delete current line
I have a simple ForEach loop
ForEach ($line in Get-Content documents.txt) {

... code ...

}

and I would like to remove that line from the original file once my code has been processed.
What would be the best approach to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

So final result should be empty file (since you process every line with your current code)? If so, wouldn't it be easier to just empty the file?

Yes, eventually the file should be empty. However, I would like to delete line by line, every time a line has been processed.

I think you miss the PowerShell Pipeline (/streaming) concept: if you don't pass the current $Line (aka omit the ... code ...), you actually delete the line. Thus: ForEach ($line in Get-Content document.txt) { } | Set-Content new.txt. Or even more PowerShell-ish: Get-Content document.txt | ForEach-Object { } | Set-Content new.txt.

You question is definitely unclear and needs more context. Please edit you question and add an input example and an output example of what you expect. See also: how to ask. Based on you comment, it looks like you want to continuously update a document based on a process condition which is a complete mystery for anyone reading this...

IF your question is about doing something with each line in a text file and afterwards empty that file, you can do:
$filePath = 'D:\SomeFolder\documents.txt'
foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $filePath )) {
    # here you process the line
    # ... code ...
}
# you have processed all lines, so empty the original file
Clear-Content -Path $filePath

IF however you mean to do something with each line that matches a condition and keep the rest, do:
$filePath = 'D:\SomeFolder\documents.txt'
$newContent = foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $filePath )) {
    # here you process the line
    # dummy code:
    if ($line -like '*anything*') { 
        # do what you need to do with that line 
        # don't output this line because you're finished with processing it
    }
    else { $line }  # output the original line
}

# now you have an array of lines you did not process and the rest is gone. Save the new lines
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $filePath

These are just examples. If you can tell us more about the documents.txt file (is it huge or small) and what you are intending to do with the 'processing', there are lots of different other ways of dealing with this.
